# Android Java load different settings based on production/staging?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I need to be able to load different settings on my onCreate function based on production/staging, my app is a react native but I need to do this in my java file here is my current code

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    Intercom.initialize(this, "android_sdk-xxxx", "xxxx");
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I would like to load different Intercom keys

Comment: can't you use `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)` ?

Comment: I'd use a simple extra setting UI where the user can set it manually. This can then be removed in the finished version.

Comment: Thanks that was it

Comment: is it mine? if so, your welcome :D

Comment: As a side note, you can also reduce your Fabric init code to simply:

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); and you'll get the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeBonnell is their way to setup Fabric for just for production?

Answer (score 2):

In your `gradle.properties` set the values for debug/staging/production

```
DEBUG_KEY=debug-key-val
STAGING_KEY=staging-key-val
PRODUCTION_KEY=production-key-val
```

Then add them to build config

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "MY_KEY", "\"${DEBUG_KEY}\""
         }
        staging {
            buildConfigField "String", "MY_KEY", "\"${STAGING_KEY}\""
         }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "MY_KEY", "\"${PRODUCTION_KEY}\""
         }
    }
}
```

Then use it as `BuildConfig.MY_KEY`. By selecting different build config `debug`, `staging` or `release` the corresponding value will be set in `BuildConfig.MY_KEY`.